# Swift fileImporter size limiting

Tags: swift, swiftui, filesize, swiftui-fileimporter

So i currently have this code:

```
.fileImporter(isPresented: .constant(true), allowedContentTypes: [.pdf]) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let url):
            if url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource(), let pdf = try? NSData(contentsOfFile: url.path) as Data {
                 if !viewModel.validateFileSize(data: pdf) {
                      viewModel.attachments.append(.init(data: pdf))
                 }
             }
         case .failure:
            // some error handling
         }
}
```

The validation of file size works as it should etc. But what i want is the limit the user from the very beginning to not even be able to select files above certain file sizes. Can this be done? I can't seem to find anything when i search for it, and exploring the `fileImporter` functionality i can't seem to see something regarding size.

Comment: If it is for macOS it is possible to use NSOpenPanel directly and validate via NSOpenSavePanelDelegate.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, sadly it's not for macOS.